# Servicestack Authentication get auth/logout

Tags: servicestack

I'm noob to this and I'm trying to use auth/logout to log the user out from everywhere that the user is authenticated from the client. I get the respond 200 that the get request made through, but when I check test-webpage.com site the user is still logged inn.

Request URL:http://test-webpage.com/api/authenticate/logout

Request Method:GET

Status Code:200 OK

Remote Address:[::1]:80

Somehow the url works if I put it in the addressbar..

EDIT:

I noticed that the request ss-id is empty when I'm sending a post/get to the other client. Can this be a bug or something?
When I'm authenticate to the other client. I can see that my client is sending an request and within that request it contain ss-id, ss-opt and ss-pid. But when sending a post/get auth/logout the request/respond's ss-id, ss-opt and ss-pid are empty. I'm debugging in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

To [logout a user in ServiceStack](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#logout) you need to send an empty **POST** request to `/auth/logout` or if using the C# Service Clients:

```
client.Post(new Authenticate { provider = "logout" });
```

Comment: Yes i know, but as I said when I send the request I get a status 200 which is ok. But I'm still logged in on the site I sent request to.

Comment: I also used Post, but get the same result.

Comment: I noticed that the request ss-id is empty when I'm sending a post/get to the other client. Can this be a bug or something?

Comment: @longhuynh you need to POST to the logout route with the authenticated client you want to logout, having no session means you're posting from the wrong client

Comment: I got two client that use servicestack authentication and share the same user. I authenticate to client2 from client1. What I'm trying to do is to log the the user out from client2 at client1. When I authenticate to client2 from client1 I can see that i get session cookie from the response. Do I have to keep the session cookie somewhere to use it again? I thought it was stored in the browser https.

Comment: @longhuynh one client can only be authenticated as one user at any one time, authenticating as a different user stops them from being authenticated as the initial user. Cookies are what maintains the authenticated Users session and automatically stick to the client they were authenticated with.

Comment: If I know the session cookie. How can I send a POST request to client2 from client1 to logout the user? Can I use auth/logout?ss-id=xxxx or something?

Comment: @longhuynh You can replace the [Session Cookies on the HTTP Client](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#cookie-session-ids) use [HTTP Headers to send Session Ids](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#use-http-headers-to-send-session-cookies), if you enable `Config.AllowSessionIdsInHttpParams=true` then you can add `?ss-id` on the QueryString.